# MAMP PRO Apache server won't start

Tags: apache, mamp, mamp-pro

After I tried to use Dynamic DNS the Apache server has stopped running. I updated MAMP PRO to the latest version, reset all Templates, check for another http process, but nothing helped. There are no errors in the logs. I made a video of the bug: https://vimeo.com/255845597